# TPC-DS query generator does not generate all queries

Tags: sql-server

I have downloaded the DSGEN tool from the TPC-DS web site and already generated the tables and loaded the data into MS SQL server.

I am using the following command to generate the SQL statements(on windows):

dsqgen /input ../query_templates/templates.lst /directory ../query_templates /dialect sqlserver /scale 1

The command gives a single query_0.sql file as output and it has only 22 queries out of 99 queries. Also in the command prompt, an error is shown as given below:

RUNTIME ERROR: Distribution over-run/under-run 
Check distribution definitions and usage for cities
index=-1, length=1000

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Try the -VERBOSE option to see if there are additional information generated by dsqgen.
Also, the version of templates downloaded from tpc.org are missing some DEFINES.

Comment: I tried adding the Verbose option but it shows an additional message 'Parsed 99 queries' along with the above error message. But still the query_0.sql has the same result i.e. 22 queries.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. I found the GitHub project of TPC-DS toolkit, and [downloaded their cities.dst](https://github.com/gregrahn/tpcds-kit/blob/master/tools/cities.dst) to try my luck. And it works!! Yeah haha.